# How to allow domain groups access to SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, domain, sql

I'm sure this is a simple problem, bu I've looked for days...

I have a SQL server that is part of a domain.  The domain has many many users.

I want to allow select permissions to anyone within a particular group on the domain.

Right now I have to add a SQL user for every domain user,  I'm sure there is a better way?

```
CREATE USER [Bob] FOR LOGIN [Domain\Bob]
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE TO "Domain\Group"
```

bob is a member of group

Answer (score 6):

Transact-SQL:

```
use master ;
create login [DOMAIN\Group] from windows ;
use <database> ;
create user [DOMAIN\Group] from login [DOMAIN\Group] ;
grant select on object:: <schema>.<object> to [DOMAIN\Group] ;
```

You can create a SQL Login and a Database User from a Windows group. Note that Domain Users still connect as their user account - the SUSER_SNAME() function will return DOMAIN\user (not DOMAIN\Group).

Answer (score 1):

Create a security group in ADUC.

Add the users to the group.

Create a SQL login for the group.

Map the SQL login to the appropriate SQL roles, databases, permissions, etc.